# Adding UP, Down, Left, Right buttons to select a cell

Tags: javascript, button, tabular

I have a simple question for you. I have some code here that allows a user to tell how many rows and columns they want in a table. I have that already figured out. What I can't figure out is how to add Up, Down, Left and Right buttons so they can select a certain cell in the table. Here is what I need it to look like:

[image: What I need it to look like]

Here is the code I have so far:

**Javascript:**

```
function createTable()
{
var num_rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
var num_columns = document.getElementById('columns').value;
var theader = '<table border="1">\n';
var tbody = '';

for( var i=0; i<num_rows;i++)
{
    tbody += '<tr>';
    for( var j=0; j<num_columns;j++)
    {
        tbody += '<td>';
        tbody += 'Cell ' + i + ',' + j;
        tbody += '</td>'
    }
    tbody += '</tr>\n';
}
var tfooter = '</table>';
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="tablegen">

  <label># of Rows: <input type="text" name="rows" id="rows"/></label> <br/><br />

  <label># of Columns: <input type="text" name="columns" id="columns"/>   </label><br/><br />

  <input name="generate" type="button" value="Generate"    onclick='createTable();'/><br /><br />
</form>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

How am I able to take this code and add the buttons to my table to select a certain cell?

Thank you for your feedback and any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "select" a cell?

Comment: I mean I want to color (select) one cell of the table. Make navigation buttons move the selection within the table. If I press the up button it will go to the cell above it. If I press the right button it will move the selection to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Give each cell a unique id.  Row 1 cell ids: 11, 12, 13, ..., 1 *n*; row 2 cell ids: 21, 22, 23, ..., 2 *n*.  Have a variable or object property that keeps track of the active cell (the highlighted one). On button click, get the id of the appropriate cell by adding or subtracting from the appropriate digit of the cell id.

For example:

```
<style>
#tab{
  height: 102px;
  width: 102px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
td{
  border: .5px solid blue;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
</style>

<body>

  <div id ="main">
    <table id="tab">
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="up">up</button>
  <button id="down">down</button>

  <script>
    window.onload = function(){
      function genGrid(n,m){
        for (var i = 0; i<n;i++){
            var row = document.createElement('tr')
            row.id = "row"+i
          for(var j=0; j<m;j++){
            var cell = document.createElement('td')
                cell.id = String(i+1)+String(j+1)
              cell.innerText = cell.id
              cell.style.color = "red"

             row.appendChild(cell)
          }
          document.getElementById("tab").appendChild(row)
        }
      }
      genGrid(4,4)

      // manually choosing active cell and bg color 
      var activeCell = "11"
      document.getElementById("11").style.backgroundColor = "yellow"

      document.getElementById('up').onclick = function(){
        var newId = parseInt(activeCell.slice(0,1))-1
            if(newId > 0){
          var oldCell =document.getElementById(activeCell)
            oldCell.style.backgroundColor = "white"

          var id = String(newId)+activeCell.slice(1,2)
            var newCell = document.getElementById(id)
            newCell.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"

          activeCell = id
        }
      }
      document.getElementById('down').onclick = function(){
        var newId = parseInt(activeCell.slice(0,1))+1
        var rowLength = document.getElementsByTagName('tr').length

        if(newId <= rowLength){
          var oldCell =document.getElementById(activeCell)
            oldCell.style.backgroundColor = "white"

          var id = String(newId)+activeCell.slice(1,2)
           var newCell = document.getElementById(id)
               newCell.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
          activeCell = id
        }
      }

    }
   </script> 
 </body>
```

Comment: Can you give an example with js fiddle?

Comment: I guess I am just not understanding what you are saying. I am new to javascript... I learned a little but not a lot

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: What you gave me put a whole other table in my page. What can I do to my existing code up top to make that work. I also need up down right and left buttons. I'm just so confused..